# Parallel Processing and maintaining order in the consumer end - Kafka + Camel

Tags: apache-kafka, concurrency, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I have this use case where we consume data from Kafka. The messages in Kafka will be associated with a key to maintain order/sequence in each partition. Now when I consume these messages, I have to process the messages in parallel and also I should not miss the sequence of messages grouped by a key.

To achieve parallelism, we can use threads, but ordering is not guaranteed. Ordering can never be compromised in our use case. Appreciate any help in achieving parallelism + ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem your describe is a very typical one in the world of distributed systems. It is for instance addressed in JMS using the concept of **Message Grouping**. Basically a JMS broker provides a guarantee that any messages that belong to a specific group will always be consumed by a common consumer, so that the FIFO ordering is respected (within a group).

I'm not a Kafka specialist but I guess there should exist a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is exactly solved by Confluent's [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC) - you can tell it to process by KEY, as concurrently as you want. By using PC, you can processing all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes. It will also ensure that ordering is maintained, and that record ack's are committed correctly back to the broker.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).